# Prediction from Zero Inflated Models?

Tags: prediction, generalized-additive-model, zero-inflation

I have fitted a two stage generalized additive model to zero inflated data ("hurdle model"). I am modeling fishery spatial data (catch rates) as a function of different environmental variables (temperature, Chlorophyll, etc). I would like to predict fish abundances, but I'm kind of lost with the procedure.

I have used GAMs and linear models before, so I'm familiar with the `predict` functions in R. However, I now have two models for one single prediction (such as fish abundance *given* probability of occurence, or the prediction of the count model given the prediction of the binomial model). My first approach was to multiply the predictions, but that would assume that both events are independent, which is not the case. I also explored conditional probability, but without much success.

Comment: How exactly is your model set up?  Do you have a distribution for $Y$ when it's positive and some probability of being positive?

Answer (score 2):

This is a nice question.

You don't specify what R packages and functions you use, so I'll take [the excellent vignette for the `pscl` package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/pscl/vignettes/countreg.pdf) and walk along that. Specifically, I'll jump off the description of a hurdle model in section 3.5.

As described in the vignette, you can download the example data file [here](http://www.jstatsoft.org/article/view/v016i09). Save it locally. Then we can load it, extract the columns we want, load the package and fit a hurdle model:

```
load("DebTrivedi.rda")
dt <- DebTrivedi[, c(1, 6:8, 13, 15, 18)]
require(pscl)
fm_hurdle0 <- hurdle(ofp ~ ., data = dt, dist = "negbin")
```

So, how do we predict from `fm_hurdle0`? Of course, we first have to specify *for what* we want to predict. As always for `predict` functions, this means filling a `data.frame` with regressor information for the scenario we want to predict for:

```
newdata <- data.frame(hosp=1,health="average",numchron=2,
    gender="male",school=10,privins="yes")
```

Now, we can look at the specific `predict` method for objects of class `hurdle` like this:

```
?predict.hurdle
```

The key parameter is `type`. By default, this is `"response"`, that is, the conditional mean given covariates:

```
predict(fm_hurdle0, newdata=newdata)
       1 
6.682801
```

Thus, our point prediction for this new instance is 6.68.

However, I'd argue that the point prediction is definitely not everything. After all, we are fitting a specific hurdle model because variance is "nonstandard" - we have zero inflation. So we should definitely try to get an idea of the overall shape of the likely response. This means that we really want the full *predictive density*. Happily, we can get that using `type="prob"`:

```
predictive.density <- predict(fm_hurdle0, type="prob",newdata=newdata)
predictive.density
          0          1         2          3          4          5 ...
1 0.0876322 0.09924771 0.0983676 0.09212974 0.08377478 0.07480663 ...
```

Let's visualize that, including the predicted mean as a vertical line:

```
plot(as.numeric(colnames(predictive.density)),predictive.density,
    col="grey",type="h",lwd=3,
    xlab="Outcome",ylab="Predicted probability")
abline(v=predict(fm_hurdle0, newdata=newdata))
```

[image: predictive density]

For double-checking, we can recover the predicted mean from the predictive density (up to numerical accuracy):

```
sum(as.numeric(colnames(predictive.density))*predictive.density)
[1] 6.682788
```

You can also have `predict.hurdle` give you

- the predicted mean from the count component (without zero hurdle) with `type="count"` and
- the predicted ratio of probabilities for observing a non-zero count with `type="zero"`, which is a somewhat complicated beast - see the help page `?predict.hurdle` on this.

If you use a different function, this may give you some ideas but may not be enough. You may then want to post a follow-up question focusing on the R aspects [at StackOverflow in the R tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/r).

Finally, as I wrote, I strongly recommend looking not only at the predicted mean, but at the entire predictive density as illustrated above. If you want to check how good your predictive density is and you have some holdout data, you can use *discrete proper scoring rules* to check the calibration and sharpness of your predictive density. A good place to start is [Wei & Held (2014), "Calibration Tests for Count Data", *TEST*, 23, 787-805](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2Fs11749-014-0380-8).